# FastObjects.NET(is an OODB from Versant) performance in Real Scenarios?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

FastObjects.NET Saves the whole class object(if marked with attribute `Persistent`) at once in file system(using serilization or similar technology).

They are promissing that it is even faster then normal SQL DB approach. My team also thought it is better and faster to save the whole object once instead of each field one by one.

Definition of their [website](http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/fastobjects/):

> FastObjects .NET 10.0 fully conforms
>   to the Microsoft.NET 2.0 framework.
>   Tightly integrated with Visual Studio
>   2005, it offers a developer-friendly,
>   object-oriented alternative to a
>   relational database for .NET
>   persistence.

I want to have your **experiences of using FastObjects in production scenario**? They are promising for Indexing/Transaction/clustoring/replication.

Comment: The company name is Versant, not vArsant :). Also AFAIK, it is an OODB, not an ORDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guys at Versant have actually deprecated the FastObjects product in favor of their newer more scalable database for .NET  ... which is their prior Linux/UNIX version just called Versant or the Versant Object Database.

As I understand it, they recently released a version 8.0 of The Versant Object Database which includes a .NET binding which is just like the old FastObjects API.   The Versant Object Database is running some seriously demanding applications .... e.g American Stock Exchange options trading systems, Sabre - Travelocity reservations systems ( original application for which IBM developed the mainframe ), HPC compute clusters for space agency, etc.

So, now you can get that super scalable high performance database which stores pure objects ( no DDL required ) for the .NET platform and fully integrated with Visual Studio.

http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/objectdatabase/VOD_NET/

Hope this helps....
-Robert

Comment: This is great, So this is better choice for normal web applications.

Should it be considered good choice for ERP type applications also? because those application requires other supporting applications. I think SQL would be better...

Comment: An update to this:
"However, for VOD (Versant Object Database) we discontinued our .NET support a while ago.". Link: http://community.versant.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/12512/Default.aspx